# How to extract a string that is present between two brackets?

Tags: c++, c

For example if the string is:

> XYZ ::[1][20 BB EC 45 40 C8 97 20 84 8B 10]

The output should be:

> 20 BB EC 45 40 C8 97 20 84 8B 10

```
int main()
{
    char input = "XYZ ::[1][20 BB EC 45 40 C8 97 20 84 8B 10]";
    char output[500];
    // what to write here so that i can get the desired output as: 
    // output = "20 BB EC 45 40 C8 97 20 84 8B 10"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also what should happen to the 1 as it is a string between 2 brackets?

Comment: You need to replace `char input = "....."` with `char * input = "....."`, btw

Comment: Do you want a C solution or a C++ solution?

Comment: David: doesnt matter...... C or C++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, you could do this with a scanset conversion (though it's a bit RE-like, so the syntax gets a bit strange):

```
sscanf(input, "[%*[^]]][%[^]]]", second_string);
```

In case you're wondering how that works, the first `[` matches an open bracket literally. Then you have a scanset, which looks like `%[allowed_chars]` or `%[^not_allowed_chars]`. In this case, you're scanning up to the first `]`, so it's `%[^]]`. In the first one, we have a `*` between the `%` and the rest of the conversion specification, which means `sscanf` will try to match that pattern, but ignore it -- not assign the result to anything. That's followed by a `]` that gets matched literally.

Then we repeat essentially the same thing over again, but without the `*`, so the second data that's matched by this conversion gets assigned to `second_string`.

With the typo fixed and a bit of extra code added to skip over the initial `XYZ ::`, working (tested) code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    char *input = "XYZ ::[1][20 BB EC 45 40 C8 97 20 84 8B 10]";

    char second_string[64];
    sscanf(input, "%*[^[][%*[^]]][%[^]]]", second_string);

    printf("content: %s\n", second_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that. But when I compiled in codepad, I get the warning `unknown conversion type character '^' in format` here's the code: http://codepad.org/ySur30IZ Am I missing something?

Comment: I think there's a typo in the pattern.  The character immediately after the second `%` should be a `[`, which is missing.

Comment: @JamesKanze Even after adding `[` I'm getting junk characters as output. http://codepad.org/P5crly7A Any thoughts?

Comment: @RageshChakkadath To be clear, I would _not_ use this solution.  I'd use a regular expression on an `std::string`.  If you use it: 1) check the return value, which says how many fields have been processed, and 2) add a width specifier for field you're capturing, to avoid buffer overflow.  As to what's happening in your case, Jerry seems to have ignored the characters which will precede the first `[`; the result is that the function fails if the first character in the string is not a `[`, and it doesn't go any further.  Which leaves the output variable in an undefined state.

Answer (score 6):

Just find the second `[` and start extracting (or just printing) until next `]`....

Comment: Using regular expressions (if this approach is availible to OP) is another way.

Comment: Is there any inbuilt standard C function available which can extract the desired string for me ?

Comment: @Vikas Chhipa The easiest would be `substr`.

Comment: Actualy, I am reading a file Line-By-Line. And...as soon as I encounter a string "XYZ ::[1][20 BB EC 45 40 C8 97 20 84 8B 10]" ......I need to extract the portion "20 BB EC 45 40 C8 97 20 84 8B 10" into a characher pointer. Then I need to pass this extracted string to some other function for further processing.

Comment: @VikasChhipa, is it always the same string you are looking for?

Comment: @Vikas Chhipa, if the string needs further processing, I think there is no need to _first_ extract the sub-string (unless it is required by your homework). Just start from the first double digits of hexadecimals following the second [ and goes on.

Comment: There will be many strings present inside the file. But, the format will be the same......for example

Line 1: -A{sdf}::[1][21 2B 6C 2E 84 8B 00]
Line 2: -B{qqq}::[1][83]
Line 3: -C{msg}::[1][11]
Line 4: -D{sdf}::[7897][1]
Line 5: -E{ale}::[1][2]
Line 6: -F{log} ::[1][1]

Comment: @Vikas Chhipa, if so, the sub-string you are looking for will always be between the second (and last) pair of [ and ]. Thus, just find the positions of the pair (`find_last_of` and `find_first_of`) and `substr` it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) if you are willing to convert to `std::string`

If you don't know the location of brackets, you can use `string::find_last_of` for the last bracket and again `string::find_last_of` to find the open bracket.

Comment: Look at the input closely. First and last brackets are not going to help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, say, your file looks like this:

```
XYZ ::[1][20 BB EC 45 40 C8 97 20 84 8B 10]
XYZ ::[1][Maybe some other text]
XYZ ::[1][Some numbers maybe: 123 98345 123 9-834 ]
XYZ ::[1][blah-blah-blah]
```

The code that will extract the data will look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //opening the file to read from
    std::ifstream file( "in.txt" );
    if( !file.is_open() )
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the file";
        return -1;
    }
    std::string in, out;
    int blockNumber = 1;//Which bracket block we are looking for. We are currently looking for the second one.

    while( getline( file, in ) )
    {
        int n = 0;//Variable for storing index in the string (where our target text starts)
        int i = 0;//Counter for [] blocks we have encountered.
        while( i <= blockNumber )
        {
            //What we are doing here is searching for the position of [ symbol, starting
            //from the n + 1'st symbol of the string.
            n = in.find_first_of('[', n + 1);
            i++;
        }
            //Getting our data and printing it.
        out = in.substr( n + 1, ( in.find_first_of(']', n) - n - 1) );
        std::cout << out << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output after executing this will be:

```
20 BB EC 45 40 C8 97 20 84 8B 10
Maybe some other text
Some numbers maybe: 123 98345 123 9-834 
blah-blah-blah
```

Comment: I dont need the brackets.... The o/p should be = bla bla bla. Instead of [bla bla bla]

Comment: The results will be interesting if the string doesn't have the correct format.  (`n + 1`, where `n == std::string::npos`, gives `0`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, in one of the comments OP said that all the strings have this format, that's why I did it this way.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall The strings are obviously input from somewhere.  Which means that the only way to guarantee that all of the strings have this format is to verify that they do.  Processing text without the necessary error handling is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is something along the lines of:

```
std::string
match( std::string const& input )
{
    static boost::regex const matcher( ".*\\[[^]]*\\]\\[(.*)\\]" );
    boost::smatch matched;
    return regex_match( input, matched, matcher )
        ? matched[1]
        : std::string();
}
```

The regular expression looks a bit complicated because you need to match
meta-characters, and because the compiler I use doesn't support raw
strings yet.  (With raw strings, I think the expression would be
`R"^(.*\[[^]]\]\[(.*)\])^"`.  But I can't verify that.)

This returns an empty string in case there is no match; if you're sure
about the format, you might prefer to throw an exception.  You can also
extend it to do as much error checking as necessary: in general, the
more you validate a text input, the better it is, but you didn't give
precise enough information about what was legal for me to fill it out
completely.  (For your example string, for example, you might replace
the `".*"` at the beginning of the regular expression with
`"\\u{3}\\s*::"`: three upper case characters followed by zero or more
whitespace, then two `':'`.  Or the first [] group might be
`"\\[\\d\\]"`, if you're certain it's always a single digit.

Answer (score 1):

This could work for you in a very specific sense:

```
std::string str(input);

std::string output(input.find_last_of('['), input.find_last_of(']'));

out = output.c_str();
```

The syntax isnt quite correct so you will need to look that up. You probably need to define your question a little better as well as this will only work if you want the brcketed string at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Using string library in C. I'll give a code snippet that process a single linewhich can be used in a loop that reads the file line by line. NOTE: `string.h` should be included

```
    int length = strlen( input );
    char* output = 0;

    // Search
    char* firstBr = strchr( input, '[' );
    if( 0 != firstBr++ ) // check for null pointer
    {
        char* secondBr = strchr(  firstBr, '[' );
        // we don't need '['
        if( 0 != secondBr++ )
        {
            int nOutLen = strlen( secondBr ) - 1;
            if( 0 < nOutLen )
            {
                 output = new char[nOutLen+1];
                 strncpy( output, secondBr, nOutLen );
                 output[ nOutLen ] = '\0';
            }
        }
    }

    if( 0 != output )
    {
        cout << output;
        delete[] output;
        output = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error!";
    }
```

Comment: This will, of course, crash if the string doesn't have the correct format.

Comment: @JamesKanze Didn't you see? string is hard coded to the variable `input`. So there is no chance for a crash. I tried to address the primary concern of OP from the code he provided. Error handling part if reading from a file must be done appropriately.

Comment: If the real problem is only the single, hard coded string, then the problem is trivial, because the answer is already known.  The hard coded string is obviously only an example.  (The problem doesn't make sense if there is no "input".)

Comment: @JamesKanze Got it! Updated the answer! Pls check whether its ok. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Well, at least it won't crash.  It still seems overly complicated: using `std::string` and regular expressions, you can get both full error checking _and_ extraction of the results in two or three lines.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, it can be done easily using STL. But, OP was asking for a method that uses 'inbuilt C function' in one of his comments. That's why I wrote it like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex to get what is inside "<" and ">":

```
// Regex: "<%999[^>]>" (Max of 999 Bytes)
int n1 = sscanf(source, "<%999[^>]>", dest);
```